# Не работают css медиа-запросы

Tags: css, opencart

У меня есть обычная верстка и на ней работают медиа-запросы, но потом я верстку натянул на opencart и там медиа-запросы не работают.

Пример медиа-запроса:

```
@media (max-width:1024px){
header .menu {
    display: none;
}
}
```

Comment: Их могут перекрывать другие запросы из других CSS файлов. Попробуйте добавить `display:none!important`, если сработает, то причина в каскаде, если нет - то либо в синтаксисе, либо в чем-то еще

Comment: Не работает...(

Comment: В devtools это правило видно?

Comment: Не видно.......

Comment: киньте ссылку что ли

Comment: http://shop.cb33457.tmweb.ru/

Comment: Посмотрел сайт по ссылке, хочу сказать, что очень хорошо сверстано! Резиновая верстка с применением vw это нечто)

Comment: Лучше не использовать vw или всё хорошо?